# Showing Dirichlet function is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Consider the Dirichlet function $D:[0,\pi] \rightarrow \Bbb{R}$ given by

$D(x):=\begin{cases} 0 &\text{if } x\in [0,\pi] \cap \Bbb{Q},  \\{}\\ 1 &\text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$

Then give an argument for why the function $D$ is measurable.

I'm looking for some direction on this proof. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: $1_{\mathbb{Q\cap[0,\pi]}}(x)=1-D(x)$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: $1 - D(x)$ is the indicator function of a set of measure $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use the definition of measurability (for functions) directly. A function is measurable if the pre-images of Borel measurable sets are Lebesgue measurable.

In this case, you can say exactly what sets are the pre-images of ANY sets in the codomain. There are finitely many and you can go through and list them.

Once you have done this, prove that each of the sets on your list is measurable. They should all be sets that you can easily determine this for.

Obviously I could fill in the blanks but it seems like you are best off trying it yourself, good luck.

Comment: Dear jwg: A function is measurable if the pre-images of *open* sets are measurable. Regards,

Comment: This is true in R. It is not true in general.

Comment: Dear @jwg: are you so sure? Chapter 18, Proposition 2 of Royden's *Real Analysis* : "Let $(X,\mathcal M)$ be a measurable space and $f$ a real-valued function on $X$. Then $f$ is measurable if and only if for every open set $\mathcal O$ of real numbers, $f^{-1}(\mathcal O)$ is measurable." Regards,

Comment: I am sure. I said that it is true in R (with the usual notion of measurable sets). This is because the open sets generate the sigma-algebra of measurable sets. Your counterexample refers to functions into R, with the usual notion of measurable sets. The fact that the book is called *Real Analysis* might be a clue. A function from an arbitrary measure space into another arbitrary measure space (not necessarily a topological space), is measurable by my definition. HTH.

Comment: You are right, but the case being considered here is that of measurable functions on the real line. If you prefer to think of these functions as measurable functions between measurable spaces - which is fine, of course - you must endow the domain $\mathbf R$ and the target $\mathbf R$ with different sigma-algebras. So to say that a real-valued function on the real line is measurable if and only if the preimage of measurable sets is measurable is extremely misleading, because the same words are used twice in the same sentence to refer to two different measurable spaces.

Comment: Presumably, your (noble) intention is to help the O.P. understand his problem, and not to further complicate his situation with subtle ambiguities which a person first encountering measure theory would be unable to disentangle. If that is so, then I would recommend modifying your answer in order that it become not only technically right if one is willing to argue in its defense, but also helpful. Regards,

Comment: I think 'Sorry. I corrected you, but I was wrong.' is the expression you're looking for.

Comment: jwg: why the need to be cocky? I stand by my claims. I have edited your post to clarify it. Feel free to revert the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the preimage of measurable sets $X$ for all the four possible combinations of $0 \in/\notin X$ and $1 \in/\notin X$. Remember that the finite combinations (union, intersection, ...) of measurable sets are measurable, and that countable unions of disjoint sets are measureable too, and that their measure is the sum of the individual set's measuers

Answer (score 0):

I find another very interesting solution to show that the Dirichlet Function is measurable

$${{\chi }_{\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]}}\left( x \right)=\left\{ \begin{align}
  & 1\text{ for }x\in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1] \\ 
 & 0\text{ for }x\notin \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1] \\ 
\end{align} \right.$$ For instance if you have $\lambda$ the Lebeasgue measure you know that:

$$\lambda (\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1])=0 \implies D(x)=0 \text{,}\space  \lambda \space \text{a-e}$$

but $f(x):=0$ is measurable since continuous.