# Proving Lebesgue measurability of Dirichlet-like functions

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Dirichlet function $D:[0;1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined by

$$ D(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 & \text{if } x \not\in \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$

We say that a function $f:E \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable in measure space $(X,\Sigma)$ iff

$$ \forall c \in \mathbb{R} \;\{ x\in E | f(x) < c \}\in\Sigma.$$

This definition is equivalent to other 3 statements with respectively $\le, \ge, >$ inserted in $f(x) < c$.

Using the statement $ \forall c \in \mathbb{R} \;\{ x\in E | f(x) > c \}\in\Sigma$ it is easy to see that $D$ is measurable by considering cases where $x\le0$, $0<x\le1$ and $x>1$.

But how would I test if a similar function $F:[0;1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is measurable?

$$ F(x) = \begin{cases} e^x & \text{if } x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ xe^x & \text{if } x \not\in \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$

P.S.
There is a [similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383286/showing-dirichlet-function-is-measurable) which apparently uses a different definition of measurability.

Comment: Just a 'more you know' moment - generally speaking we talk about functions being measurable if they are defined on some measure space with values in a topological space. For example if $f : X \to Y$ where $X$ is a measure space and $Y$ a topological space we say $f$ is measurable iff $f^{-1}(U) \in \Sigma$ for every $U \in \tau$ (the preimage of an open set is measurable). It so happens that for real valued functions (even extended real valued) this happens to be equivalent to what you wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions $x \mapsto e^x$ and $x \mapsto x e^x$ are both continuous, hence measurable (you can also use your criterion to show that they are increasing, hence measurable).

Using the fact that $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ is measurable, and that sums and products of measurable functions are measurable, we find that
$$
F(x) = \mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]} \, e^x + \mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{Q}^c \cap [0,1]} \,x e^x
$$ 
is measurable as well.

Answer (score 1):

$$F(x)=e^x\cdot\left[(x-1)\cdot(1-D(x))+1\right]$$

Then use the properties of measurable functions with respect to the arithmetic operations and the continuity of $e^x$.

Answer (score 1):

A more literal answer...  Fix $c$.  The set $Q:=\{x \in [0,1]\; : \;F(x)>c\}$ is the union of two sets
$$
Q_1 := \{x \in [0,1]\; : \; e^x>c\} \cap \mathbb Q,
\\
Q_2 := \{x \in [0,1]\; : \; xe^x>c\} \setminus \mathbb Q,
$$
Show that both of these sets are measurable.